# How to move a node element in DOM with JS, jQuery or D3

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, d3.js

All:

I wonder how can I move element in the DOM with either JS, jQuery or D3:

For example:

```
<div class="container"  style="width:100%;height:100%;">
    <div class="item" style="width:50%; height:40%; float:left;">DIV1</div>
    <div class="item" style="width:40%; height:40%; float:left;">DIV2</div>
    <div class="item" style="width:50%; height:40%; float:left;">DIV3</div>
    <div class="item" style="width:40%; height:40%; float:left;">DIV4</div>
</div>
```

So basically right now the layout shown is 2X2, what I want to do is just drag DIV1 and move to DIV4 then they can swap position. I kinda thinking using the way how array swap element, copy the DIV1 DOM element from DOM array, copy the DIV4 to that place and copy DIV1 to DIV4 place in that array.

But I do not know if this is possible and if so, how to implement this?

Thanks

Comment: yup, that's certainly possible.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks, AND ......

Comment: and... i'm not going to write your code for you.

Comment: @KevinB Well, thanks though.

Comment: Do you mind removing the _jquery_ flag. This has nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: @War10ck It is about how to implement this in jQuery

Comment: _"I wonder how can I move element in the DOM with D3: ..."_ - I think this statement is incorrect then. Can you update your question please? It's a little confusing...

Comment: @War10ck Thanks, yes, u r right, I need add others

Comment: @Kuan No worries, just wanted to clarify. I was slightly confused

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the jqueryUI add on draggable support:  https://jqueryui.com/draggable/

To have the drag event update your backend, you would want to bind a function to the "stop" event for the containers that queries the resulting order of the divs.

This is going to involve adding some behaviors to the DIVs so they behave the way you envision.  Any div not being dragged will need to know when you are attempting to drop another div onto the page where some defined handle on the object (or the mouse pointer) is before or after the element not being dragged.

So, some pseudo code:

```
onStop: function(item){ checkPointerLocation(); insertDraggedObjectBeforeNearest() }
```

Comment: I tried that, but still can not figure out 2D dragging and swap. Do u happen to know any tutorial or example like the problem I mention, from DIV1 to DIV4?

Comment: I don't know of a specific tutorial for this.  It's more than just drag and drop but not too complex I think.  I added some suggestions above.